# How do I download the full list of individuals who liked a discussion?

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2016

When I hover over the number of likes below the discussion, it only shows a maximum of 20 individuals who liked a post; if there are over 300 likers, how am I able to pull out this data? I've read similar posts but never found a solution to this.